# Find out binary dependencies of gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies, rpm, rpmbuild

I want to build rpm with my Ruby app and its gems. As far as some gems depends on binaries I want to find out them automatically. For example `nokogiri` gem depends on `libxml`. Can I fetch all this dependencies for all gems in Gemfile automatically to pack them into rpm?

Now I do it mannualy and this is boring!

Comment: normally, `rpmbuild`does such stuff automatically...

Comment: @glglgl, How does it know about binary dependencies of gems? I need to set `BuildRequires` for them manually

Comment: Often it happens that binaries and libraries are examined and dependencies to other libraries are created. OTOH, library packages  provide symbols matching to their contained libraries. But to be honest, as I didn't know what gems are, I could only answer insufficiently. But maybe(!) there are scripts which can analyze and deal with them appropriately.

Comment: The main idea of topic is to find out this script :). But looks like there is no such scritp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, this is not possible. RubyGems only records Gem dependencies. It obviously cannot record any dependencies it doesn't know about, how would that even work?

There is a [`requirements` attribute in the gemspec](http://Docs.RubyGems.Org/read/chapter/20/#requirements), but that is only intended to be human-readable, not machine-readable.

Comment: Yeap, I understand this. I was thinking about parsing extconf.rb but this is very hacky can't work in general :)

Comment: There are also dependencies which don't even show up in `extconf.rb` Just think about shelling out using `Kernel#system` or something like that.