# How to check system package dependency of a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Let's say, I have a gem:

```
curb
```

Now this requires:

```
libcurl-devel
```

system package installed on my machine (Fedora 17). How do I find out the dependency before attempting an install? This command:

```
gem dependency curb
```

only show the other gems which are required for this gem to install, not system packages:

```
$ gem dependency curb
Gem curb-0.8.1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out binary dependencies of gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903575/find-out-binary-dependencies-of-gem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, per se. The dependency is on the libcurl headers, so you could try to find those headers in the available search paths, and then make a recommendation of which package to install based on the platform being installed on, but the libcurl headers could be installed by any number of packages, or even from source, so there's no one way to say "curb requires libcurl-devel" in a general case.